# How to hook custom compiler logic based on annotations

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, compilation

I want to define a few annotations that will allow extra warnings/errors to be reported during compilation (similar in concept to the `@Nullable` and `@NotNull` annotations in **IntelliJ**).

I would like to be able to write some compiler hooks that will also add my compilation logic based on those attributes.

I want a generic hook if possible, however since we are using Eclipse - it would also be a benefit if we had that ability.

I'd like to know:

1. Is it possible? (any of the options above)
2. Where do I start?
3. I had little experience with annotations so far, so if I'm going about this the wrong way - I'd like to know that and if possible get a better direction to go with.

Thanks.

Comment: See: http://techbitsfromsridhar.blogspot.ca/2013/02/java-compiler-plug-ins-in-java-8-use.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Java Annotation Processor (see [*JSR 269: Pluggable Annotation Processing API*](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=269)) for that. From [Annotation checking at compile time with Java Annotation Processor](http://javasign.blogspot.com/2009/08/annotation-checking-at-compile-time.html):

> The JSR 269 states that you can
>   implement a plug-in for the compiler
>   which can handle the annotations. This
>   plug-in can be given as parameter at
>   compile time, so your code will be
>   called when one of your annotation
>   appears in source code.

The mentioned link provides an example that will get you started.

#### See also:

- [Annotation Processing Tool (apt)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/index.html)

Comment: Second link no longer exists. Not sure where it went.